# Display available system errors in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

How can I display all available system error numbers and error messages, also show the value of `sys_nerr` by using following:

```
extern char *sys_errlist[]
extern int sys_nerr
```

?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Comment: Which platform?  The answer depends on the platform.

Comment: maybe you want `perror()`?

Comment: For this question, it is really relevant that you take a stand for either C or C++ because the error handling is dramatically different.  In C++11 we finally got [a portable way to handle system errors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error).  In C, `errno.h` and `strerror` is all we have.

Comment: I know we can find list of errors in errno.h file but how we display all those errors using c program?

Answer (score 1):

This is OS dependent, but for OSes that support these variables you can try something like:

```
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < sys_nerr; ++i)
    fprintf(stdout, "%d : %s\n", i, strerror(i));
}
```

Then if you want to get rid of error numbers that aren't used in the range [0, sys_nerr), you'd likely need to do some system specific filtering.  The following would likely work on OSX for example:

```
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < sys_nerr; ++i)
  {
    const char *errstr = strerror(i);

    if (strncmp(errstr, "Unknown error:", 14))
      fprintf(stdout, "%d : %s\n", i, errstr);
  }
}
```

Accessing sys_errlist itself directly is even more system dependent.  Entries might be NULL for unused error numbers or might have an "Unknown error ..." string there.  It depends.

Comment: I need just a simple c program which displays all system errors when I run the program.

Comment: Yeah, I think I gave you code to do that -- although it is OS dependent.  To begin with, not all systems have these variables and other systems have deprecated their usage.

Comment: I am looking to implement it in UNIX os. I know your program is right. But I need program which display complete list of all system errors.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <errno.h>
//#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  extern int sys_nerr;
  extern char *sys_errlist[];
  fprintf(stderr,"Here are the current %d error messages:\n\n",sys_nerr);
  for (i = 0; i < sys_nerr; ++i)
    fprintf(stderr,"%3d: %s\n", i, sys_errlist[i]);


  //return 0;
```

}